# Example 10.4 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have the following question: Why the integral on the right of $(4)$ can not exist? Since $Q^K\subset I^k$ then $\int \limits_{I^k}f=\int \limits_{Q^k}f$ and since $f\in C(Q^k)$ then $\int \limits_{Q^k}f$ exists. Can anyone give me a clear answer to this remark?

Answer (score 1):

Up to that point, Rudin has defined (Riemann) integrals only in cubes, i.e., products of closed intervals. To extend the definition to more general domains, such as $k-$simplexes, one needs to do some more works. It is possible, and Rudin has only started above to describe the way.

Comment: Yes that's true. But why integral over $I^k$ can not exists? I can't understand it.

Comment: I guess that it's obvious because since $f\in C(Q^k)$ then exists $\int \limits_{Q^k}f$. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Had this same question and then realized that the integral $\int_{I^k} f$ may not exist because while $f$ is continous on $Q^k$, it suddenly becomes $0$ on $I^k$ and thus might be discontinuous on $I^k$, so now Rudin must justify that this integral still exists.